# VF tag inline if condition show profile photo else show default photo

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to add the profile else add the default image from static resource somehow i am not able to see the image if there is no profile.

```
<div class="contact-profile-pic"  style="background-image: url(!IF({!pocDetails.userThumbPhotoURL} == '')? {!$Resource.DefaultProfilePhotoSmall} : {!pocDetails.userThumbPhotoURL});background-position: center;background-size: 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Below is the browser output for image

```
<div class="contact-profile-pic" style="background-image: url(!IF( == '' )?/resource/1506729657000/DefaultProfilePhotoSmall : );background-position: center;background-size: 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;">  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
url({!IF(pocDetails.userThumbPhotoURL == '', 
$Resource.DefaultProfilePhotoSmall, pocDetails.userThumbPhotoURL);
```

Comment: Or even `{!BLANKVALUE(pocDetails.userThumbPhotoURL, $Resource.DefaultProfilePhotoSmall)}`

Comment: An even better option!